# How to read files from test resources with scalatest?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I'm working in a Scala project using SBT, so the project follows the default directory structure:

```
project_name/
├── build.sbt
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   └── production.txt
│   │   └── scala
│   │       └── ...
│   └── test
│       ├── resources
│       │   └── test.txt
│       └── scala
│           └── ...
```

When I try to read the files in the resources folder, in production code, I try this, and works just fine:

```
object FileReader extends App {
  io.Source.fromResource("production.txt").getLines.toList.foreach(println(_))
}
```

But when I do try to do the same in test code:

```
class FileReaderTest extends FreeSpec with Matchers {
  "Source" - {
    "reads files from resources folder" in {
      val lines = io.Source.fromResource("test.txt").getLines.toList
      lines should be(List("Hello","World"))
    }
  }
}
```

I get a NPE exeption:

```
[info] Source
[info] - reads files from resources folder *** FAILED ***
[info]   java.lang.NullPointerException:
[info]   at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
[info]   at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:129)
[info]   at scala.io.BufferedSource.reader(BufferedSource.scala:22)
[info]   at scala.io.BufferedSource.bufferedReader(BufferedSource.scala:23)
[info]   at scala.io.BufferedSource.charReader$lzycompute(BufferedSource.scala:33)
[info]   at scala.io.BufferedSource.charReader(BufferedSource.scala:31)
[info]   at scala.io.BufferedSource.scala$io$BufferedSource$$decachedReader(BufferedSource.scala:60)
[info]   at scala.io.BufferedSource$BufferedLineIterator.<init>(BufferedSource.scala:65)
[info]   at scala.io.BufferedSource.getLines(BufferedSource.scala:84)
[info]   ...
```

When I try to read `production.txt` file in the test, it works just fine too. So my guess is that for some reason, the test resources folder is not being loaded in the classpath. So with this, I've researched about SBT, and it seems that by default, the `src/test/resources` folder is the default one already, in fact, just checking in the SBT shell, it yields the following:

```
> show test:resourceDirectory
[info] <path to project>/src/test/resources

> show test:unmanagedResources
[info] * <path to project>/src/test/resources

> show test:unmanagedResourceDirectories
[info] * <path to project>/src/test/resources
```

So obviously, I'm missing something, but no clue on where to continue researching.

By the way, I'm using Scala 2.12.4, SBT 1.0.2 and scalatest 3.0.4

**Update**

Seems the problem was related to either SBT build or the IDE, as I have done may experiments with the `build.sbt` file, changing and playing around `unmanagedResources`, `resourceDirectory`, and some others in `Test` scope, and at the end there was a corruption somewhere.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, and after removing all my experiments with the SBT `Test` scope, deleting the `.idea` folder and re-importing the SBT project, it just worked fine.

Also in regards of the question being a possible duplicate of other questions, I thought there was a difference, because at first it worked with the resources located at `src/main/resources` but not with the `src/test/resources`.

Comment: What is the content of `test.txt`? From the look of the stack trace, the `Source.getResource` call has completed. That function returns a `BufferedSource`, and `BufferedSource.getLines` appears at the bottom of the stack trace. Is it possible that the error arises in processing the content of the file, instead of not finding it?

Comment: @MikeAllen it had just 2 lines, "Hello" and "World" as you can see in the assertion of the test, it wasn't very explicit, sorry about that. Anyways, for some reason, I tried it again, and now it works just fine, my guess is that somehow, the SBT build was "corrupt" by all the experiments I've tried editing the `build.sbt` file with different options, with a reload it got fixed.

Comment: @Suma that question was my starting point doing research, and it answers to how to read resources from `main` resources, but my question was related to `test` resources. Anyways, as I said it my previous comment, I think the issue was related to SBT or the IDE, not Scala code. Still thanks for pointing out.