# Source.fromResource() doesn't read file from src/main/resources during tests

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have some files in `src/main/resources`. During the main program run, I can load them fine using `Source.fromResource(pathWithoutSlash)`. But in tests, if I try to use the same method to load them, it returns null unless I copy over the files to `src/test/resources`. This is an issue for some large sized files.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of this: [How to read from test resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921715/how-to-read-files-from-test-resources-with-scalatest)

Comment: That question never got any answers

Comment: I tried it in my intellij, it is working fine. Are you using mvn or sbt?

Comment: @proximator sbt , this is my build.sbt: https://gist.github.com/aliakhtar/97bd7967499ab48f4860b81ffdc981e4

Comment: During tests, by default, `Source.fromResource("hello/world.txt")` will try and use `src/test/resources/hello/world.txt` and if it doesn't exist, then this will default in using `src/main/resources/hello/world.txt`. Tried again with scala 2.12.2, seems to work fine.